# What is a coninvolutary matrix?

Tags: matrices

I'm reading Horn's [Congruences of a Square Matrix and Its Transpose](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504001533). It shows that every square complex matrix is *-congruent to its transpose via a "con-involutary" matrix. I'm curious what this con-involutary matrix is. I didn't find it in the literary....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize at the beginning of the document, they mentioned that coninvolutary matrices are matrice $S$ such that $\overline{S} S = I$...